# Could a written name in the book of Life be blot out (erased)?

Tags: revelation, soteriology, free-will, book-of-life

Revelation 3:5 (DRB):

> 5He that shall overcome shall thus be clothed in white garments: and **I will not blot out his name out of the book of life**. And I will confess his name before my Father and before his angels.

From Revelation 3:5, Could a written name in the book of Life be blot out? Blot out=erase.

I mean, is Free will present?, Even after being written in the book of Life, i.e: choice between good and evil is present, even after being written in the book of Life.

Thus, a man can get in, or get out, or re-enter in the book of Life.

Comment: If  you understand this Great testament you would answer all of your question look :" Then do they not reflect upon the Qur'an? If it had been from [any] other than Allah, they would have found within it much contradiction."

Comment: @zeraouliarafik I believe in all Holy Books. I believe in the Bible, I believe in the Vedas, I believe in the Holy Quran.

Comment: Probably this is your answer which it is of mine also , look " The Messenger has believed in what was revealed to him from his Lord, and [so have] the believers. All of them have believed in Allah and His angels and His books and His messengers, [saying], "We make no distinction between any of His messengers." And they say, "We hear and we obey. [We seek] Your forgiveness, our Lord, and to You is the [final] destination."

Comment: Do you really believe in ALL HOLY BOOKS as you said?  If so, in truth, you are saying, you do not believe in any of them. You will find why so in these Scriptures: John 3:16; Luke 15:11-32; 1 John 1:9; 2 Peter 3:15; Roman's 9:22; 1 Peter 3:20.

Comment: All names are written in the book of life from before Creation, no where in Scripture are names added. But names are erased

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Ps 69:28 we find this:

> May they be blotted out of the Book of Life  and not listed with the
> righteous.

Recall that this was written under divine inspiration, but King David.  There are numerous examples where people choose to reject God's free salvation which God respects by adjusting the entries in the Book of Life.  Here are further examples of this, using different metaphors but the message is the same:

- Eze 18:21-28 also teaches that the wicked can reform and be saved, and the righteous can apostatise and be lost.
- Rom 11:17-21 discusses the warning that people who had been grafted into the “olive tree” of the Christian community could be broken off if they were unfaithful.
- 1 Cor 9:27 Paul says he disciplines his body to keep it under control so that after preaching to others he does not become a castaway/disqualified.  That is, Paul believed that it was possible that he could lose his way and become lost.
- 1 Tim 6:10, For the love of money is the root of all kinds of evils.  It is through this craving that some have wandered away from the faith and pierced themselves with many pangs.
- Similarly, Heb 6:4-6 also teaches that some “who have once been enlightened, who have tasted the heavenly gift, who have shared in the Holy Spirit…” can fall away.
- 2 Peter 1:10, “make your calling and election sure”.  This clearly allows for the possibility of losing one’s election.
- 2 Peter 2:21, “It would have been better for them not to have known the way of righteousness, than to have known it and then to turn their backs on the sacred command that was passed on to them.”
- 2 Peter 3:17 contains a very stern and sobering warning to be on guard that we do not fall from our secure position.  Verse 14 contains a similar warning.
- 1 Cor 10:12 also contains a stern warning from Paul, “If you think you are standing firm, be careful that you don’t fall.”
- Gal 6:9 says, “Let us not become weary in doing good, for at the proper time we will reap a harvest if we do not give up.”

  … and so forth.

Comment: Perhaps verses like you have listed are from man's perspective while verses like John 6:37-39, which plainly declare that Jesus doesn't lose any, are from God's perspective.

Comment: pleased edit for clarity: "Recall that this [Is 69:28]  was written under divine inspiration, but King David." There's no such chapter in Isaiah, nor was it written by King David!

Comment: @DanFefferman - quite correct.  This should have been psalms not Isaiah. Now corrected. Many thanks

Comment: I've talked about this with a Bible teacher before and this list will definitely help me have a much livelier discussion! Did you mean to write *by King David?

Answer (score 2):

I see a few good answers but, what is missing here? Where is the Holy Spirit in all of this?
OSAS is the truth. How so? Thanks for asking.

John 14:16-18

> <sup>**16**</sup> And I will pray the Father, and he shall give you another Comforter, that he may abide with you for ever; <sup>**17**</sup> Even the Spirit of truth; whom the world cannot receive, because it seeth him not, neither knoweth him: but ye know him; for he dwelleth with you, and shall be in you. <sup>**18**</sup> I will not leave you comfortless: I will come to you.

Notice Jesus said that the Comforter may abide with you forever. Look at verse 14, it says he dwelleth in you. Jesus said he will abide in us forever. Look at what Paul says,

Ephesians 1:13, 14

> <sup>**13**</sup> In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise, <sup>**14**</sup> Which is the earnest of our inheritance until the redemption of the purchased possession, unto the praise of his glory.

God now seals us once we come to Christ. How long are we sealed for? Paul answers this:

Ephesians 4:30

> And grieve not the holy Spirit of God, whereby ye are sealed unto the day of redemption.

Paul also said:

1 Corinthians 6:19, 20

> <sup>**19**</sup> What? know ye not that your body is the temple of the Holy Ghost which is in you, which ye have of God, and ye are not your own? <sup>**20**</sup> For ye are bought with a price: therefore glorify God in your body, and in your spirit, which are God's.

We have a temple where the Holy Spirit now lives in us, and God has bought and paid for us through his Son Jesus Christ.
OSAS is the truth. Nowhere do you find any scriptures saying we can lose the Holy Spirit or even be broken off.

Comment: In case people don't know. OSAS stands for "Once saved, always saved."